# Python - cxfreeze keeps saying file/directory non-existant

Tags: python, batch-file, cx-freeze, python-3.2

I've got some very basic code which works, and I want to turn it into an exe.

Since I'm using Python 3 because it seems so much cleaner than other Python editions, I've not been able to use Py2Exe, so I installed cxfreeze instead.

Once I run cxfreeze with the following command:

```
cxfreeze "C:\Users\pc user\Documents\Python\First project\Main.py"
```

It says something about the directory/file not existing. That's about as in-depth as it goes. The exact error is something like "Could not find the path specified"

cxfreeze itself is 'detected' by cmd because I don't get a non-recognised error when I just run "cxfreeze". Both cxfreeze and python are on my PATH environment variable.

Naturally I've triple-checked the directory and it is correct.

I've tried variations of this command, including

```
python cxfreeze "C:\Users\pc user\Documents\Python\First project\Main.py"
cxfreeze C:\Users\pc user\Documents\Python\First project\Main.py
python cxfreeze C:\Users\pc user\Documents\Python\First project\Main.py
```

Can anyone bring light to this situation?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you put the file in a location which doesn't have any spaces in the path?

Comment: Interesting idea. I'll check that now. I hope I do, because if I don't it'll mean I can't use my documents folder :L

Comment: cxfreeze C:\Scripts\Main.py "The system cannot find the path specified"

Comment: I run it on win7 64bit with py32 using the same folder tree as yours and a print("Hello") Main.py file and it works perfectly. The only thing is that I executed `cxfreeze.bat` at the Scripts directory. Before that I had to change the root directory in that file (by default is `X:...`

Comment: `C:\Python32\Scripts>cxfreeze.bat "C:\Users\pc user\Documents\First project\Main.py"`  -->
`creating directory C:\Python32\Scripts\dist`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Get cxfreeze binary. I got mine from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). The file is
  `cx_Freeze-4.2.3.win-amd64-py3.2.‌exe` (my PC is win7 64-bit with 64b Python).
- Install it on Python 3.2. A file cxfreeze.bat is created in
  `C:\Python32\Scripts`.
- Open the .bat file. Change the contents:

  `@echo off`
  `X:\Python32\python.exe X:\Python32\Scripts\cxfreeze %*`

  with

  `@echo off`
  `C:\Python32\python.exe C:\Python32\Scripts\cxfreeze %*`

  or equivalent for your particular path
- Open your cmd console and change your directory to
  `C:\Python32\Scripts` (I have Python 2.6 as default so that
  Python32/Scripts is not in the path. Whatever your case this is the
  safer method)
- Execute the cxfreeze.bat file as shown:

,

```
Microsoft Windows [Versión 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Reservados todos los derechos.

C:\>cd c:\Python32\Scripts

c:\Python32\Scripts>cxfreeze.bat "C:\Users\pc user\Documents\First project\Main.py"
copying C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\bases\Console.exe -> c:\Python32\Scripts\d
ist\Main.exe
copying C:\Windows\system32\python32.dll -> c:\Python32\Scripts\dist\python32.dll
...............................................
................................................. 
m zipimport
m zlib

copying C:\Python32\DLLs\bz2.pyd -> c:\Python32\Scripts\dist\bz2.pyd
copying C:\Python32\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd -> c:\Python32\Scripts\dist\unicodedata.pyd

c:\Python32\Scripts>
```

- A dist folder is created in `C:\Python32\Scripts\` that includes your
  Main.exe file

Comment: Fixed my current problem but now it's saying %1 is not a valid win32 executable. The problem was it was saying C:\Python32-64 in the batch file, I guess (It had C:\), but after fixing that I've now got an error

Comment: Not sure how you got that batch file if you used the same packages I indicated to you. You must have it clear you did **exactly** the same steps, with the same files as I described. It took to me 5 minutes to install everything and  generate an executable that I checked and found it was working perfect. So it is difficult to say what is going on in your case. Are you sure you dont have things around from the old install ?

Comment: I got it working now. Apparently, despite having a 64 bit system, and windows install, and probably Python install too, I needed a 32 bit cx_freeze install. Seems wierd to me but it's working now. Thanks for helping, either way.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with cxfreeze on the following setup:

- Win7 64-bit OS
- 64-bit python 2.7.3 (from python.org)
- cxfreeze 4.3 for Win 64-bit + Python 2.7 (from http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/)

After some investigation it turns out that all of the scripts that were installed by the cxfreeze package into my 'c:\python27\Scripts' directory (cxfreeze, cxfreeze.bat, cxfreeze-quickstart, cxfreeze-quickstart.bat) had bad references to my python base path.

Inside those scripts there were references to a base path of 'c:\python\32-bit\2.7' and 'c:\python\64-bit\2.7'.  I edited the scripts and fixed the paths(changed the base path to 'c:\python27'), and that fixed the problems.  **Check the python base install path on your system.**

Not sure why these paths were wrong.  I installed Python from the official python.org site (as alluded to by cxfreeze docs) and I did not modify the install location.