# Cx_Freeze DLL load failed

Tags: python, dll, python-3.x, exe, cx-freeze

I have been trying to use cx_freeze for some time now, and yet the same error always occurs

```
    import cx_Freeze.util
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid win32 application
```

I have tried with both 32 and 64 bit, and have tried both setup.py and cxfreeze.bat

what I am asking is, how do I make it work?

Comment: give more details. Is it windows ? 32, 64-bit python ?, linux?, did you clean everything from the failed install  before new install ? Did you check it?

Comment: 64 bit windows 7, 64 bit python 3.2.2, I'll try reinstalling after cleaning everything, what do you mean "check it"?

Comment: check it -> sometimes windows uninstallers actually does not uninstall everything, and let things behind. So, I mean checking if folders, config files, etc are actually deleted

Comment: Just now uninstalled it with revo, and I'm checking

Comment: check also my answer + comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774063/python-cxfreeze-keeps-saying-file-directory-non-existant/8774644#8774644)

Comment: I uninstalled, checked, followed your instructions exactly, got the same error.

Comment: umh... I have same environment like yours, and cxfreeze worked with no problem at all. Can not help. Still, the exception you get says you have some 32/64 bit incompatibility between cxfreeze and python installations. So maybe you are not aware, but it is there. Maybe you have another python installed side by side with python 3.2 ?

Comment: The `%1` in the error smells like it is an indication of where the error is. I'm pretty sure whatever is called with a "%1" as a parameter shouldn't be called like that. Try to seek that out. Put a Pdb just before you get that error and see what happens.

Comment: possible duplicate of [cx_Freeze/ldap: ImportError: DLL Load Failed %1 is not a valid Win32 application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597126/cx-freeze-ldap-importerror-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had the same problem and this was my solution.

I am using Python 3.2 for windows 64 bit and my library installations were all for 64 bit, including cx_freeze. When I tried to "freeze" a program that imported the PyQt4 package, I got the error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid win32 application
```

In my case, the problem was that the cxfreeze script was copying two DLL files (QtCore4.dll and QtGui4.dll) from my MATLAB installation, rather than from my Python installation. The MATLAB DLLs were 32 bit whereas the Python DLLs were the required 64 bit files.

Read the messages displayed when you run the cxfreeze script to build your exe files. The last few messages should be "copying ...dll-> ....dll". Check the filenames and make sure that all the files are actually being copied from your Python installation and not some other program.

If they are being copied from elsewhere (as in my case) you can simply copy them over yourself after the build. Otherwise, you will have to change your path not to include the folder containing the 32 bit DLLs from whatever program they belong.